# Highcharts "area" not hovering properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts, coffeescript

I'm using Highcharts to display the amount of leads we get per day:
[image]
However, when I hover over the graph, it doesn't work properly. Look at the position of the mouse and the position of the info-box.
[image]
[image]

Here's my code:

```
  if $('#swedbank_leads_per_day_graph').length > 0
  data = PageData.swedbank_leads_per_day
  swedbankLeadsPerDay = new Highcharts.Chart
    chart:
      renderTo: 'swedbank_leads_per_day_graph'
      type: 'area'
    title:
      text: null
    tooltip:
      formatter: ->
        date = new Date(this.x)
        return date.toDateString() + '<br />' + "#{this.y} lead(s)"
    xAxis: 
      type: 'datetime'
      # tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 # Days
    legend:
      enabled: false
    series: [
      data: data,
      pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    ]
    yAxis:
      title:
        text: 'Finance leads per day'
```

(Note: using Coffeescript)

When using columns, it works fine and as it should. Any tips?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle example?  Note that with an area series type, the hover that triggers the tool tip is hovering over a data point, not the area itself.  The tooltip will also persist until the mouse leaves the series - this means that what you are seeing could potentially happen with everything working "correctly", if you hover over a point, move your mouse across the chart without coming closer to another data point...  FWIW

Comment: Creating a fiddle is near to impossible, as I'm using a lot of data, stuff to calculate that data etc. I did create a video of the graph though, so you can see what happens if I hover like you suggest:
http://f.cl.ly/items/1U2K0H3t3h0j0S2x1r21/graph.mov

I have a graph with "area" working in another area, without any trouble, so it surprises me it doesn't work as it should here.

Comment: What are you using plotOptions for 'column' type if your chart type is area?

Comment: Some left behind code of some testing I did. Will remove it.

Comment: Can you at least show us what your data variable contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't sorted for xAxis - make sure your values will raise. Also, I advice to upgrade Highcharts to 3.0.5 version - then in JS console you will get error message with unsorted data (and more others).

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for your answer! Coincidentally, we just found out that the console outputted Error 15, saying that the data has to be sorted ascending. Will mark your answer as the right answer, as, well, it is the right answer :D

Comment: Could you maybe also tell me how I get the data to reach to the edges? The graph now starts one day (kind of) from the left and ends one day from the right. My other graph does this automatically. Does this have to do with sorting as well?

Comment: Try to set `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to 0. Or `startOntick` and `endOnTick` to true. It's hard to say without seeing some live code.

Comment: Solution was removing `pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000` from the `series:` part. :)